# Incremental build not working in MAUI for android target in .NET 8?

Tags: android, maui, .net-8.0

I have a MAUI application currently running in NET 7. My main workflow is to complie and deploy directly to local android device directly from visual studio. Every time I hit F5 the application compiles and is deployed to the phone within a few seconds.

Today I tried to upgrade the project to target NET 8 and noticed that it takes a very long time to compile and deploy to the phone. Even if there are no changes at all to the code base it seems the application is always rebuilt.

To rule out that I have some strange things going on in my project I tried to create two new default MAUI applications in Visual studio. One targeting NET 7 and one targeting NET 8 and then I tried to build them in command line a couple of times to see the difference in build time. See image below.

[Buildtime comparison between net7 and net8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6ya3.png)

The first build is of course expected to take some time since it is built for the first time but build #2 and #3 should be faster since no changes are made. This works a expected i NET 7 but not in NET 8.

Am I doing something wrong? Are there any new properties that I need to enable to get the same build behaviour as before?

Comment: Did you use the Visual Studio 2022? I can't reproduce your problem in my visual studio 2022 preview.

Comment: Yes these problems began when I upgraded to Visual studio 17.8.0 with support for NET 8. It seems to work as expected for windows builds, but not for android builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Github issue for this.

TLDR: Uninstall and reinstall VS 2022 from scratch solved the issue for me.

[Git hub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19282)